# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: read-only file system: unknown

Tags: linux, docker

For some reason it is not working when I try and mount a file.
Any ideas?  thanks
Here is the command

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped --network host --name dewi_php -v /home/pi/ext_files/media/audio_books/:/usr/src/myapp:ro -v /home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php:/usr/src/myapp/index.php -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.4-cli php -S localhost:8919
```

Here is the error message

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting "/home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php" to rootfs at "/usr/src/myapp/index.php" caused: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/631378511a84343806b1a17da860e4c51bf64e9008942aadbc7b9ba4c1858e85/merged/usr/src/myapp/index.php: read-only file system: unknown.
```

The file exists:

```
ls /home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php
+ ls -althN --color=auto -r /home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 2.2K Mar 22 15:33 /home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php
```

Here is the docker container inspect

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin $ docker inspect dewi_php
+ docker inspect dewi_php
[
    {
        "Id": "862825de9a06222b7ae0fd0c91bc5f7df6d6ebf1bc7b4f5c09d9a40847636f77",
        "Created": "2022-03-22T16:17:25.171962372Z",
        "Path": "docker-php-entrypoint",
        "Args": [
            "php",
            "-S",
            "localhost:8919"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "created",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 128,
            "Error": "failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:75: mounting \"/home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php\" to rootfs at \"/usr/src/myapp/index.php\" caused: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f1d3d45fb10c8d6c44958a0ff482b991b9cd982e0218bf8cd75d637a2a1c7ba/merged/usr/src/myapp/index.php: read-only file system: unknown",
            "StartedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:61b1e58469c23eda8dc7565fe32c1f3e82627f27296f66b50b59f6e7f30ee53a",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/862825de9a06222b7ae0fd0c91bc5f7df6d6ebf1bc7b4f5c09d9a40847636f77/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/862825de9a06222b7ae0fd0c91bc5f7df6d6ebf1bc7b4f5c09d9a40847636f77/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/862825de9a06222b7ae0fd0c91bc5f7df6d6ebf1bc7b4f5c09d9a40847636f77/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/862825de9a06222b7ae0fd0c91bc5f7df6d6ebf1bc7b4f5c09d9a40847636f77/862825de9a06222b7ae0fd0c91bc5f7df6d6ebf1bc7b4f5c09d9a40847636f77-json.log",
        "Name": "/dewi_php",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/pi/ext_files/media/audio_books/:/usr/src/myapp:ro",
                "/home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php:/usr/src/myapp/index.php"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f1d3d45fb10c8d6c44958a0ff482b991b9cd982e0218bf8cd75d637a2a1c7ba-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/baf48181bf16fdeda3662cd076a620193e614138dbbaf331e28e363e0a92a47a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ae5c591d546b70077175e49d6d9f1643535dcd13e4ab322a987539c4f6e5ebb7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d7b359987e83d46f9484717915cec0e5d579ada9983a7aec45e3e9391ff113e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fc26805bf35074fc380d815a072c6d0c3c51bf4c9e3e8cb67896ba2a04c68de6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f44fe541897acd89a66c9618c2c4b1d8bc972d5796545e6fc45c8d64df65d297/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0156486281b7ee677365e79322650e584f4eaa777e2d45d62820044cdb2e56e6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5222af13938c45277c12062f455837985a9f0963ae5bc679633cfd83ee0e6083/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2fda0c2a7dcd8c982520f5c90628e7306873e484d401a5d098d462a3e7e2c135/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ba6356c734311a347337049deb9adaf840be9f53cebf14bceb27d40145ea45c/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f1d3d45fb10c8d6c44958a0ff482b991b9cd982e0218bf8cd75d637a2a1c7ba/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f1d3d45fb10c8d6c44958a0ff482b991b9cd982e0218bf8cd75d637a2a1c7ba/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f1d3d45fb10c8d6c44958a0ff482b991b9cd982e0218bf8cd75d637a2a1c7ba/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/pi/ext_files/media/audio_books",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/myapp",
                "Mode": "ro",
                "RW": false,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/pi/code/dot-files/serverconfig/code/server_docker/bin/php_files/index.php",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/myapp/index.php",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "raspberrypi",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
                "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie",
                "GPG_KEYS=42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D 5A52880781F755608BF815FC910DEB46F53EA312",
                "PHP_VERSION=7.4.28",
                "PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.28.tar.xz",
                "PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.28.tar.xz.asc",
                "PHP_SHA256=9cc3b6f6217b60582f78566b3814532c4b71d517876c25013ae51811e65d8fce"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "php",
                "-S",
                "localhost:8919"
            ],
            "Image": "php:7.4-cli",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/src/myapp",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-php-entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "b3b32cba3746ffbe5429ed1f5f8652236b0c908e015f334f960e1ead1a4d91d5",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "d0797258b71630ab5faed70463e29220db43f8dcfad431e82fc110fa14a0c9b8",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```